# Image won't display MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello evryone (im using MVC5),
i generate image from Chart in Html Helper Extension

```
    public static string GetUrlFromChart(this HtmlHelper helper, Chart chart)
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/graphs/");
            string filename = path + Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";
            chart.ToWebImage("jpg").Save(filename);
            return filename;
        }
    }
```

by viewmodel i send data to view and i tried to show them to user.

```
<img src="@Html.GetUrlFromChart(@Model.my_chart)" width="400" height="250"/>
```

Image generate properly, in correct path, but application cannot show me it,
its only white rectangle 
[image]

when i copy image source to windows explorer.
[image]

i get that image.

[image]

but it seems to wont work with

```
<img></img>
```

anyone know how to display System.Web.Helpers.Chart like image, or display data like chart ?

Comment: I think your `GetUrlFromChart` method should be returning a path that is relative to your web root (e.g. /App_Data/graphs/{guid-here}, not a full path as you are now.

Comment: im sorry, im not mension that.
extension is in another project in solution

Comment: According to the docs, `ToWebImage()` takes "jpeg" or "png" as arguments. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage.imageformat(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: relative path
string path = "~/App_Data/graphs/";
doesnt help, now it shows icon not find image.
change extension to .jpeg also doesnt help

Comment: dont change the extension, try changing the `ToWebImage` argument.

Comment: by doc, the default arg is "jpeg"

Comment: your argument is `"jpg"`

Comment: im sorry mxmissile. i didnt make it clear. i change extension to .jpeg (file) and change arg to "jpeg". "check if working", then i remove arg "check if working". change to png "check if work". repeat whole cycle with absolute path and relative path

Answer (score 0):

Hello mate you should return the image rather than the file path
    I don't know about this Chart object so I just change the code to a generic one

change your code to:

```
 public static ActionResult GetUrlFromChart()
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/graphs/");
            string filename = path + Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";
            var image = chart.ToWebImage("jpg");
            //save your image.
            return File(image.GetBytes(),  "image/jpeg");
        }
    }
```

in the view:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetUrlFromChart", "Yourcontrollername")"/>
```

Comment: and theres no way to to that using helpers ?